# Multi database in the same method

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, multi-database

My app has 2 databases, `Db1` (has table `dbo.Student`) and `Db2` (has table `dbo.School`). I created 2 AppService to access them
When I tried to get data from both of them, It only uses the connection to `Db1` (Could not found table `dbo.School` in the current context). So how can I get the data from Db1 and Db2 at the same time

```cs
private readonly IStudentAppService _studentAppService;
private readonly ISchoolAppService _schoolAppService;

public BranchAccountController(IStudentAppService studentAppService,
ISchoolAppService schoolAppService)
{
     _studentAppService = studentAppService;
     _schoolAppService = schoolAppService;
}

public async Task<PartialViewResult> GetStudent(int? id)
{           
     //Repository 1 (Database 1)
     var student = await _studentAppService.GetStudentForEdit(new NullableIdDto { Id = id });
     //Repository 2 (Database 2)
     var school = await _schoolAppService.GetSchoolList();

     //bla bla      
}
```

> Update 1:
>   I tried to get the school before student and face the below error: 
>   The transaction passed in is not associated with the current
>   connection. Only transactions associated with the current connection
>   may be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `Begin` separate units of work:

```cs
public async Task<PartialViewResult> GetStudent(int? id)
{           
    List<SchoolDto> schools;
    StudentDto student;

    using (var uow = UnitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
    {
        // Repository 1 (Database 1)
        student = await _studentAppService.GetStudentForEdit(new NullableIdDto { Id = id });
        uow.Complete();
    }

    using (var uow = UnitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
    {
        // Repository 2 (Database 2)
        schools = await _schoolAppService.GetSchoolList();
        uow.Complete();
    }

    // ...
}
```